# How to equal the custom adapter field to database field

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I just only want to get receiver id from database to here and equal with the custom list receiver id gravity set

```
if(customList.getReceiverid( ) .equals (database.getreceiverid(pos))) {
    viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    viewHolder.time.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
else
{
    viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    viewHolder.time.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

My database code like below

```
public ArrayList<CustomList> getreceiverid(String receiverid) {
    ArrayList<CustomList> array_list = new ArrayList<>();


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME, null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        CustomList item = new CustomList(" type ", " senderid ", " receiverid ", " message ", " time ");
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        item.getReceiverid();
        contentValues.put(RECEIVERID, receiverid);


        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is the issue you faced.

Comment: `item.getReceiverid();` does nothing on it's own, so what is `contentValues.put(RECEIVERID, receiverid);` supposed to do? What are you doing with `contentValues`? It isn't used. Plus, you are returning an empty list.

Comment: If `customList.getReceiverid()` returns a number (I assume?), why are you trying to `.equals()` against a list?